# Why mmap throws error while using MAP_FIXED?

Tags: linux, mmap

Using Ubuntu 16.04, kernel 4.17.4

I am trying the following code where I have defined a shared memory and mapped current process's address space to the shared memory. When I use MAP_FIXED in mmap() it shows:

> mmap: Invalid argument

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STORAGE_ID "/SHM_TEST"
#define STORAGE_SIZE 4096




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int res, temp;
    int fd;
    int len;
    pid_t pid;
    void *addr;
    char data[STORAGE_SIZE];

    fd = shm_open(STORAGE_ID, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("open");
        return 10;
    }

    res = ftruncate(fd, STORAGE_SIZE);
    if (res == -1)
    {
        perror("ftruncate");
        return 20;
    }

    addr = mmap(NULL, STORAGE_SIZE, PROT_WRITE, MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);

    if (addr == MAP_FAILED)
    {
        perror("mmap");
        return 30;
    }

    res = munmap(addr, STORAGE_SIZE);
    if (res == -1)
    {
        perror("munmap");
        return 40;
    }

    // shm_open cleanup
    fd = shm_unlink(STORAGE_ID);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("unlink");
        return 100;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The reason I am using MAP_FIXED is I will manually put an address instead of `NULL` (tried this and got same error). What do I need to do to use `MAP_FIXED` with mmap()?

Comment: The code shown here will obviously fail because you pass a NULL pointer.  Please show the code where you pass an actual address.  How did you determine what address to use, and are you making sure that the address is page aligned?

Comment: Note that `MAP_FIXED` with a truly fixed address is almost always a bad idea.  It is very hard to be sure that your chosen address doesn't already have something important mapped there, and if it does, it will silently be replaced and everything will break.  The only safe way to use it is with an address where you have already mapped something that you know is safe to replace, e.g. returned by a previous non-fixed `mmap`.

Comment: Beginners often want to use `MAP_FIXED` to ensure that several processes all map a shared memory segment at the same address, so that they can share absolute pointers into the segment.  But this is not possible to do safely and reliably.  You have to redesign your code to use relative offsets, e.g. array indices instead of pointers.

Comment: @NateEldredge basically I want to map some pages which are already mapped to somewhere else. For example, say there are 10 pages defined when I am running the process. I will choose 2 pages among those 10 pages which will contain some variables and functions and map the 2 pages to the shared memory. Is that possible using mmap? this is a research project so it is okay if it is not the safest option.

Comment: I don't think I understand.  What do you mean by mapping "to" shared memory?  If you're effectively trying to share memory that wasn't initially mapped from a file or shared memory segment, then AFAIK no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

One way to use `MAP_FIXED` is the following. First, you reserve a 'large' virtual memory block:

```
void* virtual_address = mmap(nullptr, large_custom_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_NORESERVE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
```

This doesn't allocate any memory *per se*. You just reserve a range of addresses `[virtual_address, virtual_address+large_custom_size)`. Now, with this range reserved, you can call individual mmaps with `MAP_FIXED` and fill in slots in this range with real memory.

```
//Next "size_block1" will be the size of a chunk of allocated memory inside the big region 
//previously reserved:

int fd = open(path.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
ftruncate(fd,size_block1);
void* fixed_address = mmap(virtual_address, size_block1, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_FIXED, fd, 0);
```

Notes:

1. One needs to do error checking after each of the calls above and check errno.
2. One can open the file inside /dev/hugepages (properly configured) to use huge pages. In this case `MAP_HUGETLB` will also have to be added to the list of flags for mmap (e.g., `MAP_NORESERVE | MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED | MAP_HUGETLB`).
3. Subsequent mmaps with `MAP_FIXED` will have to use addresses starting with `virtual_address+size_block1`